# How do I navigate to a particular object (Tables for e.g.), I know name of, in Object Explorer without loading all the tables (object of that type)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I connect to the SQL server from SSMS over VPN and there are huge amount of objects (SPs and Tables) on DB. It takes time to load all.

Comment: Why do you need to navigate to the table/proc? I ask because there may be an alternative to navigating to it.

Comment: Basically I want to access context menu for the particular object in object explorer.

Comment: Is there a particular task you want to do with the context menu. Many of the functions on this can be achieved within the query editor window without the need for the context menu, things such as `SP_HELP`, `SP_RENAME`, `SP_DEPENDS` or the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. The more specific your question is the easier it is to provide an answer.

Comment: Doing things from UI is more intuitive to me for some tasks unlike some other tasks and that's why I feel the need of Context Menu here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the filter. Click on the object node without expanding it, then click the filter button on the tool bar above Object Explorer, and enter the name.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about just using the TSQL command language to do everything you need? That way you just have to connect a Query window and then you're off and running.

Comment: Basically I want to access context menu for the particular object in object explorer.

Comment: Sure, but anything you can do there you can do through TSQL. If you have so many objects that loading them is problematic, just running a TSQL command avoids the whole issue.